# How Can I pass a javascript variable value to MVC controller?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

Just an example:

In JavaScript, I have  two variable values:

1. movie id: 2
2. rating value: 3

I need to pass those values to MVC Controller.

Comment: U can use Ajax to send.. please post what u have tried..

Answer (score 0):

For start, the easiest way is to use ajax call from jquery.

Here is my example:

**First create action something like this. I am using index as starting action for which you should create a view, and then from that view we are passing data to Movies action**

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Movies(int movieId, int ratingValue)
    {
        string s =  movieId + " - " + ratingValue;

        return Json(s, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

**Now creating view Index from which we are sending data on button click. And then you import jquery file and use it in  tag as you can see below **

```
 <html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>Index</title>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#sendData').click(function () {
            var movie = 3;
            var rating = 2;

            var option = {
                url: '/Home/Movies',
                data: JSON.stringify({ movieId: movie, ratingValue: rating }),
                method: 'post',
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
            };

            $.ajax(option).success(function(data) {
                alert(data);
            })
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div> 
        <input type="submit" value="Send data" id="sendData" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**And you see result**

[Result in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIce7.png)